# How to disable browser autosuggestion when jquery autocomplete is on?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

When I type in an input box, my firefox browser automatically provide suggestions based on whatever I typed in this input box before. With jQuery Autocomplete enabled on this input box, before Autocomplete finish loading its suggestions, browser's suggestion comes first. How can I disable the browser suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery Autocomplete automatically adds autocomplete=off, you don't need to do this yourself.

Are you using a browser extenstion that overrides autocomplete=off? If so, it will override this.

Comment: Even after I added the code "autocomplete=off", browser changes it to "on". On this computer I'm using, I have 3 addons -- FireBug, DoNotTrack, AddtoSearchBar. Anyway, it's good to know it's not jQ's problem.

Comment: Don't work, my chrome uses native auto-complete enabled hints! =(

Comment: @EliseuB. Many browsers these days ignore `autocomplete=off`.

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is specify autocomplete="off"

```
<input type="text" value="" id="searchBox" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: this doesn't work. when the page loaded, from firebug, I can see it loaded as autocomplete="on". Maybe it's jq-Autocomplete js set it as on?

Comment: can you provide me with your markup (with the input field in it) and how you configured jqAutoComplete?

Comment: my jq code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445384/jquery-autocomplete-how-to-enable-cache  the html code is <input id="ctages-input" type="text" name="ctages-input" size="50">

Answer (score 2):

If you are using HTML5 or normal HTML then you can use the following code:

```
<input name="username" size="40" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

Lately it's better to use `autocomplete=nope`. Where `nope` is an invalid value.

With the jQuery (UI) autocomplete plugin you can use the following to change it from `off` to `nope`:

```
$('#Element').autocomplete({
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'nope');
    }
});
```