# jQuery Autocomplete: How to enable cache?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

This is my source code that use a function to push the suggestion array:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    var cache = {};
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }

    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $("#ctags-input")
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })

    .autocomplete({ 

        source: function(req, add){
            var ctags_action = 'suggest_tags';

            var term = req.term;
            if (term in cache) {
               add(cache[term]);
               return;
            }

    $.getJSON(SuggestTags.url+'?callback=?&action='+ctags_action, req, function(data) {
                var suggestions = [];
                $.each(data, function(i, val){                              
                    suggestions.push({
                        label: val.name,
                        count: val.count
                    });
                });
                cache[term] = suggestions;  
                add(suggestions);

            });
        },          
        focus: function() {
            return false;
        },

        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var terms = split( this.value );
            terms.pop();
            terms.push( ui.item.value );
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = terms.join( ", " );
            return false;
        }   
    })

    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {        
        return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + " (" + item.count+ ")</a>")        
        .appendTo(ul);
    };      
});
```

To add cache ability, jQ UI site demo directly uses response for data:

```
source: function( request, response ) {
   var term = request.term;
    if ( term in cache ) {
      response( cache[ term ] );
      return;
    }

   lastXhr = $.getJSON( "search.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
    cache[ term ] = data;
    if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
        response( data );
    }
 });
}
```

How to implement this cache demo in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `suggestions` in the cache.

```
var term = req.term;
if (term in cache) {
   add(cache[term]);
   return;
}
...
cache[term] = suggestions;
add(suggestions);
```

Comment: I updated my question, added suggestion in the cache, but it still send ajax request.

Comment: The problem is `var cache = {};`, this is emptying the cache each time you enter the function. The cache needs to be a global variable outside the function.

Comment: I just moved 'var cache = {};' outside of the function and put it at the beginning of function($). it still not using cache.

Comment: Without seeing the full code, it's hard to tell. Can you post a minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I just edited my question, that's the full code for the autocomplete. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I don't see the cache in the edited version.

Are you seeing the repeated ajax requests from different loads of the page? Remember that JavaScript scope is only within a page load; each time you go to a page, all JS variables are reset.

Comment: I didn't add the cache code in the edited question, because I think my adding was wrong. When I try the cache code, I didn't reload the page. I just type in the search term again, and saw ajax request from firebug

Comment: How do you expect us to tell you what you did wrong when you added the cache code if you don't post it?

Comment: sorry I was afraid that my wrong implication confuse you. Now I added in the question.

Comment: Looks to me like it should work. Maybe single-step the function in firebug to see what's in cache.

Comment: got a little hint-- my input value is multi autocomplete selection. The first value is using cache. if I try to type the second value, it sends request. By the way, where to view cache in firebug?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and use the Javascript console to see the contents of variables.

Comment: I set breakpoint at "var term = req.term;", when type in either first or second search term, can see the suggestions are in cache (closure scope/cache). but 1st search term loads the suggestion, 2nd search term got stopped by the breakpoint.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by multi autocomplete selection. Does this have something to do with your keydown handler? It seems to be overriding something related to autocomplete.

Comment: multi selection means I can input comma separated tags in the input box. Yes the keydown handle was copied from jq UI website's multi selection demo

Comment: If I comment out the keydown handle, the first 3 search term load from cache, start from the 4th, it sends request

Comment: I just looked at the multi-complete demo. In its source: function, it uses extractLast(req.term) before looking up the input in the completion list, so that it only processes the last item in the comma-separated list. You need to do something similar. Without this, you're using the entire input (including items that have already been completed) as the cache key.

Comment: Thanks for sorting out this problem. Could you give an example on adding the extractLast into my existing code?

Comment: Copy the split() and extractLast() functions from the demo, then change `var term = req.term;` to `var term = extractLast(req.term);`